# Search data in two different tables with pagination and score

Tags: mysql, search, pagination, full-text-search

I have two different tables

```
tbl_news(news_id, title, content)

tbl_packages(packaged_id, title, content)
```

How to search in these tables with score and pagination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood you, you need [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Here is the code, it might help you.

```
SELECT id, title, content, link FROM (
SELECT news_id AS id, news_title AS title, news_description AS content, 
MATCH (news_description, news_title) AGAINST ('$keyword') AS relevance FROM tbl_news
UNION ALL
SELECT package_id AS id, package_title AS title, package_description AS content,
MATCH (package_description, package_title) AGAINST ('$keyword') AS relevance FROM tbl_packages
)temp_sort_table
WHERE relevance >0 ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT $offset,$limit
```